# how use mysql.connector in python-flask

Tags: python, flask, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect mysql database with python-flask app.
My app.py looks like this

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

#config Database
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = 'localhost',
        password = '',
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port = 3306,
        database = 'test'
)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, rating, number, type, image from place")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return render_template('index.html', data = data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

But when I browse it "Unable to connect". MySql sever is on.
[image: php my admin browser with test database and place table]

In the terminal it shows

- Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
- WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
- Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Answer (score 0):

You are running "Pyhton app.py" in terminal.
It needs to run "Flask run" in terminal